# What is the equivalent OnScroll Event to TScrollBar for FMX?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, firemonkey

I have not come across a solution for an Event (OnScroll) handler for a TScrollBar under Delphi 10 Seattle. I chose it because it is not a TScrollBox for which I will put any content into (like a Panel or DBGrid). It is merely going to detect the mouse action (None of the MouseUp/Down/Side-to-Side have worked either) and it is going to be used as file seek tool for which it will force a bunch of TeeCharts to update, based on the direction of the scroll.

So far I have only come across incomprehensible examples consisting of WindowsMessages (WM_HScroll) and VLC.StdCtrls.TScrollBar.OnScroll

What is the efficient way to detect the ScrollBar moving besides OnChange?

It would help to be able to manipulate the ScrollBar and have it reset itself in the middle. Much like it would if I set the value much like if I set the Min = -50 and Max = 50 (0)

Comment: The OnChange event should work fine. It acts the same as OnScroll. You can set the Min and Max properties to anything you want.

Comment: I don't undestand your question, why are you looking for something *besides OnChange*. OnChange is what you are supposed to use. To reset to the middle, set `sb.Value := (sb.max + sb.min) / 2;`

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion, but I'm afraid that I didn't make myself clear enough. After the scrollbar has been moved, I want the scrollbar to move back to the original position (center)  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269799/) The link shows additional properties for the OnScroll (VCL), so I thought that onChange wasn't comparable.

Comment: What is the equivalent to Repaint for a ScrollBar?

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the limitations of the FMX `TScrollBar`, you could use the following as a basis for further enhancement (partly inspired by the link you provided).

If the control(s) you will scroll with the scrollbar has (or can be equipped with) a property to store current scroll position you may use/define such, of type `single`. For testing I just defined it as a private property of the form, and called it `sbIncremental`.

I set the properties of the `TScrollBar` as `Orientation = Vertical`, `SmallChange = 10`, `Max = 100` and `Min = -100`

Then, the `OnChange` event looks like this in my test:

```
procedure TForm6.ScrollBarChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  sb: TScrollBar;
  sbOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  sb := (Sender as TScrollBar);
  sbIncremental := sbIncremental + sb.Value;

  Label1.Text := FloatToStr(sbIncremental); // Use the new value

  sbOnChange := sb.OnChange; // Disable OnChange event
  sb.OnChange := nil;         // -"-
  sb.Value := (sb.Min + sb.Max) / 2; // Reset position
  sb.OnChange := sbOnChange; // Re-enable OnChange event
end;
```

To reset the ScrollBar position to the center, we need to disable the OnChange event temporarily.

---

Update after comments.

As I now understand, your issue is that the visual appearance of the scrollbar doesn't return to the zero position even if it's value is changed (within OnChange) to zero (with min=-100 and max=100 the zero position is in the middle). It does when clicking on the arrow buttons, but it does not if dragging the thumbgrip or clicking on either side of the thumbgrip. Visual update seems to be prevented in these two cases within the OnChange event. Also, calling ScrollBar.Repaint does not update the visual appearance. I found no way to use the OnMouseDown/OnMouseUp events. They don't appear to be linked internally?

This leaves us with following (hacky) solution: Fire a timer with a small delay, say 300 ms. When timeout occurs, the scrollbar is ready to accept new value changes and update visually. The timer also has the positive effect, that the thumbgrip moves as you click, and then moves back. Without any time between there would be no visual indication that something happens.

The OnChange event handler when using a timer

```
procedure TForm6.ScrollBarChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Use the scrollbar value
  Label1.Text := FloatToStr((Sender as TScrollBar).Value);

  // Enable reset timer
  ScrollBarTimer.Enabled := False;
  ScrollBarTimer.Enabled := True;
end;
```

And the OnTimer event

```
procedure TForm6.ScrollBarTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  sbOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  ScrollBarTimer.Enabled := False;

  sbOnChange := ScrollBar.OnChange; // store OnChange event
  ScrollBar.OnChange := nil;        // disable OnChange event
  ScrollBar.Value := (ScrollBar.Min + ScrollBar.Max) / 2; // reset position
  ScrollBar.OnChange := sbOnChange; // re-enable OnChange event
end;
```

Comment: I guess this is just a test, but what is the point sbIncrement? It just merely adds / subtracts to w/e forever incrementing / decrementing value... which ever direction the scrollbar is facing. I think the scrollbar isn't resetting because w/e affect we are having on, is a (1) ScrollBar1 and (2) sb (local variable). Isn't having a local variable only going to affect the local obj, i.e. the OnChange should be moved outside of the function to affect the global ScrollBar1.

Comment: Is the initial Sender: TObject just a copy or a Pointer to the global ScrollBar1?

Comment: The local `sb` is just a reference to the actual `ScrollBar`, which is the `Sender` parameter. The purpose is to avoid **either** to write `(Sender as TScrollBar)` all the time, **or** to use `with (Sender as TScrollBar) do`.

Comment: The point of `sbIncrement` is to add up and maintain the scroll actions even if we reset the srcrollbar after each scroll action. You can use it as a pointer to where in the file seek operation you are. You may want to put limits on it according to file size for example.

Comment: I'm sorry I even mentioned the file seek or my intent, I merely wanted to have an example for which the scrollbar would jump immediately (back) after the mouseup action was made. Yes the values are 0, but that doesn't make the scrollbar reverse its visual state. (It Should!)